# How can I call a method from within a LINQ expression?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I've my Model something maybe like this :

```
    public class Person
    {
        public virtual Guid ID { get; set; }
        public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
        public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
        //this LazyList takes IQueryable<T> in constructor
        public virtual LazyList<Role> Roles { get; set; }

        //this method to convert the object that comes from EF to my own model
        public static Person FromData(DBPerson dbPerson)
        {
            if (dbPerson != null)
                return new Person
                {
                    ID = dbPerson.ID,
                    FirstName = dbPerson.FirstName,
                    LastName = dbPerson.LastName,
                };

            return null;
        }
     }
```

Then in my Repository I've method to get all persons but i need it to give to the `LazyList<Role>` property result from other private method "getRoles".
My repository looks like this:

```
        public IQueryable<Person> GetPersons()
        {
            var list = from dbPerson in context.Persons 
                       select Person.FromData(dbPerson);
       // Here is the problem :(
            return list;
        }

        private LazyList<Role> getRoles(GUID userID)
        {
            var list = from role in db.Roles
                       where role.UserID == userID
                       select role.ToModel();

            return new LazyList<Role>(list);
        }
```

**I want something here to tell this Linq statement that i want Person.Roles to get its value from "getRoles" method**

Maybe someone will tell me to put the logic of converting the dbPerson to my Person in the repository and then put something like this :

```
        public IQueryable<Person> GetPersons()
        {
            var list = from dbPerson in context.Persons 
                       select new Person{
                    ID = dbPerson.ID,
                    FirstName = dbPerson.FirstName,
                    LastName = dbPerson.LastName,
                    Roles = getRoles(dbPerson.ID)};
        }
```

OK that will work but i really need to put the logic of converting dbPerson to my model in separate method because i'll sue it many times in my solution.

So how to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that i can't call any external method until i GetEnumerator just before calling my special method.
 And this error is raised by Entity Framework.

**So the code should be like this:**

```
        public IQueryable<Person> GetPersons()
        {
            var list = context.Persons.select(p=>p).AsEnumerable()
                      .Select(m=>m.MyExtensionMethod());
            return list;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

What about a separate method to make the conversion? This way you can reuse it.

```
public  Person ToPerson(dbPerson row, bool getDetails)
{
     Person result = new Person{
                                ID = row.ID,
                                FirstName = row.FirstName,
                                LastName = row.LastName};
     if(getDetails)
     {
         result.Roles = getRoles(row.ID)};
     }

     return result;
}
```

Comment: This kinda tricking but i need to make my convert method static.

and another thing this would make me set this method in repository but i want to use it in many places. Thank you anyway :)