# MVCCrud Using LinqToEntities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

There is a sample application called MVCCrud. This example is quite good and I would like to use it as the framework on a project that I am working on.

The problem is that MVCCrud uses LingToSQL and I would like to use LinqToEntities. I got most everything to work correctly once I converted over to LinqToEntities except one place.

In the following code on the lines  i = typeof(TModel).GetProperty(primaryKey).GetValue(p, null),
                                        cell = getCells(p)
it gives a Linq to Entities does not recognize GetValue.

Can someone help me refactor the following code?

```
            items = items.OrderBy(string.Format("{0} {1}", sidx, sord)).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize).AsQueryable();

            // Generate JSON
            var jsonData =
                new
                    {
                        total = totalPages,
                        page,
                        records = totalRecords,
                        rows = items.Select(
                            p => new
                                {
                                    // id column from repository
                                    i = typeof(TModel).GetProperty(primaryKey).GetValue(p, null),
                                    cell = getCells(p)
                                }).ToArray()
                    };
            return Json(jsonData);
```

and here is the getCell method:

```
    private string[] getCells(TModel p)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        string a = actionCell(p);
        if (a != null)
        {
            result.Add(a);
        }

        foreach (string column in data_rows.Select(r => r.value))
        {
            try
            {
                // hack for tblcategory.name
                string[] parts = column.Split('.');

                // Set first part
                PropertyInfo c = typeof(TModel).GetProperty(parts[0]);
                object tmp = c.GetValue(p, null);

                // loop through if there is more than one depth to the . eg tblCategory.name
                for (int j = 1; j < parts.Length; j++)
                {
                    c = tmp.GetType().GetProperty(parts[j]);
                    tmp = c.GetValue(tmp, null);
                }

                if (tmp.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
                {
                    result.Add(((DateTime)tmp).ToString(dateTimeFormat));
                }
                else if (tmp.GetType() == typeof(float))
                {
                    result.Add(((float)tmp).ToString(decimalFormat));
                }
                else if (tmp.GetType() == typeof(double))
                {
                    result.Add(((double)tmp).ToString(decimalFormat));
                }
                else if (tmp.GetType() == typeof(decimal))
                {
                    result.Add(((decimal)tmp).ToString(decimalFormat));
                }
                else
                {
                    result.Add(tmp.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                result.Add(string.Empty);
            }
        }

        return result.ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this `ToList()` instead of `AsQueryable()`:

```
items = items.OrderBy(string.Format("{0} {1}", sidx, sord)).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

You can't execute any external method "within" linq query.

And may you say that was working in Linq2Sql then you should know when you call any external method "Like `ToString()`" Linq2Sql will fetch all data from database then handle your query in the memory and that maybe a serious harming if you have a lot of records.

For more information look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355416)